# How to use a previous prediction model to predict values between a range of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, prediction

Q: To better understand a model, we can visualize its predictions. Use your first model to predict income from each integer age in between 18 and 80. Your predictions should be stored in a numpy array of floats called pred_age.

My Model:

```
  a1, b1 = np.polyfit(df["age"],df["income"],1)
```

What I did:

I used the following code to get the values 18-80 then stored it into x where it gets ages 18-80

```
x = np.array(df.loc[(df['age'] >= 18) & (df['age'] <= 80), ['age']],)
```

Then I did:

```
pred_age = a1 * x + b1

print(pred_age)
```

Assertion Error:
[Assertion Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo3o5.png)

[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vxCD.png)

Comment: Please provide some data.

Comment: print len(x) and see if  the size is 63 as well. if not i think that the error is with the conditions and I would remove the equals sign.